# Why my cloud chamber won't work?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

let me briefly introduce myself, I'm a highschool student from Indonesia, I'm currently making a cloud chamber for my science fair project, I did what the videos on youtube told me, but for some reason my cloud chamber won't work. Here are some pictures of my setup

So, I glued felt on top of my aquarium and soaked it with alcohol (95%), put about 4 kg of dry ice under my metal tray (baking tray) and I let the alcohol and dry ice do their job for about 15 minutes, it only showed some particles raining but I didn't see any tracks of muons. I used one bright flashlight ( about 8000 Lumens ) and the room was dark enough that I couldn't see my hand. I also covered the aquarium glass with black cloth to maximize the darkness. Can anyone help check what did i do wrong? ( and what kind of camera setup should I use to record the muons tracks? )
[image: my cloud chamber setup]

Comment: Related - [What's wrong with my cloud chamber setup?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/428412/)

Comment: It is difficult to see muons, as most of the traces are close to vertical. It is easier to test with a small alpha source. A safe source for that would be a needle with polonium-210.

Comment: see  this from CERN https://indico.cern.ch/event/508576/contributions/2322575/attachments/1360032/2057853/SCoolLAB_CloudChamber_DIYManual_2016_v2.pdf . .

Comment: *I did what the videos on youtube told me* Please link to the videos. Otherwise we're just guessing what sources of information you were following.

Comment: https://youtu.be/fWxfliNAI3U                    https://youtu.be/xky3f1aSkB8          these are my sourced

Comment: I'm actually trying to use this cloud chamber to prove the time dilation of muons, so I think using a small alpha source won't prove that time dilation exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s wrong with my cloud chamber setup?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428412/what-s-wrong-with-my-cloud-chamber-setup)

Answer (score 1):

The type of light one uses seems to make a difference.
When using a linear LED source, I saw nothing (not even the "snow"). Then I switched to an old-style  (filament bulb) flashlight, I saw the "snow" AND a few tracks. Using a point-source LED (3rd attempt) saw nothing (again). All other parameters (chamber, temperature, source) were the same. When I changed back to the filament bulb, I saw the "snow" and a nice long track.